# How to make control increase size based on resize of window

Tags: wpf, resize, controls, scrollviewer

I have a custom user control in a scrollviewer, and the content of the scrollviewer is larger than the scrollviewer size.  If I scroll to the end of the data, and then resize the window, the usercontrol does not redraw because the usercontrol's size did not change. How can I force the usercontrol's size to change in response to the scrollviewer's change in size?

I was trying to do it by manually finding the control and changing the size in the code behind when it was in an itemscontrol, but now that i switched to treeview I can't seem to figure out how to find the control.

So I was thinking what I basically want is for the resize to affect the user control in scrollviewer. I was thinking that I could either make some sort of command to send to the child control, or the easier thing is to just create an event handler for scrollviewer's SizeChanged event that again manually finds the child control and updates its size and redraws the signals.  Do I have any other options?

Comment: Is your usercontrol static or dynamic control?

Comment: I will suggest you put your scrollviewer inside a ViewBox. you ll get what you are looking for.

Comment: not sure what you mean by static or dynamic control. I will try putting the scrollviewer in a viewbox and see what happens. What is the viewbox supposed to do to the scrollviewer?